# How to pass a function from page code behind to a user control

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an application that was built out over a long time by copying and pasting code into individual pages that makes more sense as a user control.. I think.

Basically it allows the page to load/save/reset to defaults some page specific settings, so each page has code behind defines its own functions to handle those events.

I'm trying to build a user control that allows the page to pass in the handlers to the user control but haven't figured out how to do that successfully.  I'm trying to just pass the functions that are already being used.

New User Control

```
public partial class uc_SaveCriteriaControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public Action SelectedCriteriaChanged { get; set; }
    public Action ResetFunction { get; set; }
    public Action SaveFunction { get; set; }
    
    protected void SelectionUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedCriteriaChanged();
    }

    protected void Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResetFunction();
    }

    protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFunction();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Attempt to use it

```
<uc3:CriteriaControl runat="server" SaveFunction="imgbtnSaveParam1_Click" ResetFunction="imgbtnResetParams_Click" SelectedCriteriaChanged="MyParams_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

This is what an existing button looks like

```
<asp:Button CssClass="btn h-100" ID="imgbtnSaveParams" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnSaveParam1_Click" Text="Save Criteria" Width="100%" />
```

It does't like passing the function name, which makes sense, but I'm not sure how you would do this.

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Action' from its string
> representation 'imgbtnSaveParam1_Click' for the 'SaveFunction'
> property.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I might need to use event handlers like so.

```
public partial class uc_SaveCriteriaControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public delegate void ResetHandler(object sender, EventArgs data);
    public event ResetHandler ResetButtonClicked;

    public delegate void SaveHandler(object sender, EventArgs data);
    public event SaveHandler SaveButtonClicked;

    public delegate void SelectionUpdatedHandler(object sender, EventArgs data);
    public event SelectionUpdatedHandler SelectionIsUpdated;

    protected void SelectionUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectionIsUpdated != null)
            SelectionIsUpdated(this, e);
    }

    protected void Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ResetButtonClicked != null)
            ResetButtonClicked(this, e);
    }

    protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveButtonClicked != null)
            SaveButtonClicked(this, e);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

And in the parent

```
criteriaControl.SaveButtonClicked += imgbtnSaveParam1_Click;
criteriaControl.ResetButtonClicked += imgbtnResetParams_Click;
criteriaControl.SelectionIsUpdated += MyParams_SelectedIndexChanged;
```